# Tyrus client cannot reconnect on server restart when client shared container is enabled

Tags: java, websocket, grizzly, tyrus

Here is the scenario:

1. Websocket server is up
2. Tyrus client shared container is enabled
3. Tyrus client connects to server (everything is good)
4. Websocket server restarts
5. Tyrus client cannot connect to the server and throws the following exception even after the server is up:

`javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Connection failed`

6. If the client application is restarted it can connect to server again

Note: This issue will not happen if [Tyrus client shared container](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e1188) is disabled.

stacktrace:

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Connection failed.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket._connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:428) ~[tyrus-container-grizzly-client-1.11.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket.access$000(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:103) ~[tyrus-container-grizzly-client-1.11.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket$1.call(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:235) ~[tyrus-container-grizzly-client-1.11.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket$1.call(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:231) ~[tyrus-container-grizzly-client-1.11.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket.connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:249) ~[tyrus-container-grizzly-client-1.11.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer.openClientSocket(GrizzlyClientContainer.java:95) ~[tyrus-container-grizzly-client-1.11.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:663) ~[tyrus-client-1.11.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:712) ~[tyrus-client-1.11.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:866) ~[tyrus-client-1.11.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112) ~[?:1.8.0_31]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:511) ~[tyrus-client-1.11.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:373) ~[tyrus-client-1.11.jar:?]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.RoundRobinConnectionDistributor$SharedIterator.next(RoundRobinConnectionDistributor.java:146) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.15-gfa.jar:2.3.15-gfa]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.RoundRobinConnectionDistributor.registerChannelAsync(RoundRobinConnectionDistributor.java:101) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.15-gfa.jar:2.3.15-gfa]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnectorHandler.connectAsync(TCPNIOConnectorHandler.java:177) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.15-gfa.jar:2.3.15-gfa]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractSocketConnectorHandler.connect(AbstractSocketConnectorHandler.java:91) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.15-gfa.jar:2.3.15-gfa]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractSocketConnectorHandler.connect(AbstractSocketConnectorHandler.java:79) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.15-gfa.jar:2.3.15-gfa]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket._connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:386) ~[tyrus-container-grizzly-client-1.11.jar:?]
    ... 41 more
```

The NPE is coming from line `if (runners.length == 1) {` in grizzly project file RoundRobinConnectionDistributor.java:146

```
private final class SharedIterator implements Iterator {
private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

@Override
public SelectorRunner next() {
    final SelectorRunner[] runners = getTransportSelectorRunners();
    if (runners.length == 1) {
        return runners[0];
    }

    return runners[(counter.getAndIncrement() & 0x7fffffff) % runners.length];
}

@Override
public SelectorRunner nextService() {
    return next();
}
}
```

Looks like that `runners` is `null`.

Comment: Do you share the same Grizzly transport between client and server? If not - could you please create a simple maven-based test to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @alexey, could you clarify what you mean by "the same Grizzly transport"? Do you mean if both client server are using the same Grizzly version for underlying websocket connection?

Comment: not exactly, is it possible for you to create a testcase to reproduce the problem (on github?) ? thank you.

Comment: @alexey, it looks like the problem might be in Tyrus code. I am working with the Tyrus team on this https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/pull/170. I hope I get a chance to create a test case for this and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested this issue is fixed in [Tyrus 1.12](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/releases/tag/1.12) by this [pull request](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/pull/170). Thanks to @pavel and his team for taking action :)