# Tyrus wss:// websocket not passing through squid proxy

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, squid, tyrus

This is using Java 8, squid 3.1.2, and the `tyrus-standalone-client-1.12.jar`for the websocket implementation.

---

**UPDATE**:
It is still not working with Tyrus.  However, it appears the problem is not with squid because when I make Chrome use the proxy and connect right here to SO, the connection to `wss://qa.stackoverflow.com` goes through the squid proxy and works fine.

---

I am using the test program given in the accepted answer to [javax.websocket client simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452903/javax-websocket-client-simple-example/26454417) to try to get a squid proxy running.

However, I've changed it to use the websockets.org echo server and so the URI was changed from `wss://real.okcoin.cn:10440/websocket/okcoinapi` to `wss://echo.websocket.org`.

When I don't use a proxy the test program works fine with `wss://echo.websocket.org` and `ws://echo.websocket.org`.

When I specify a JVM-wide proxy via `-Dhttp.proxyHost`, `-Dhttp.proxyPort`, `-Dhttps.proxyHost`, and `-Dhttps.proxyPort` the `ws://` URI works fine but the `wss://` one does not.

I have verified (with tcpdump) that traffic is going to the proxy, that the test program is sending a `CONNECT` to the proxy, and that the proxy sends back a `Connection established`.  However, at that point nothing else happens:

```
# tcpdump -n -l -s 0 -S -X  'host 172.16.99.15'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:21:45.361023 IP 172.16.99.21.36521 > 172.16.99.15.3128: S 1720321489:1720321489(0) win 14600 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 1135431 0,nop,wscale 5>
        0x0000:  4500 003c 5696 4000 4006 c5e0 ac10 6315  E..<V.@.@.....c.
        0x0010:  ac10 630f 8ea9 0c38 668a 05d1 0000 0000  ..c....8f.......
        0x0020:  a002 3908 1e74 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..9..t..........
        0x0030:  0011 5347 0000 0000 0103 0305            ..SG........
17:21:45.361763 IP 172.16.99.15.3128 > 172.16.99.21.36521: S 1626710395:1626710395(0) ack 1720321490 win 14480 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 1127109 1135431,nop,wscale 7>
        0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 4006 1c77 ac10 630f  E..<..@.@..w..c.
        0x0010:  ac10 6315 0c38 8ea9 60f5 a17b 668a 05d2  ..c..8..`..{f...
        0x0020:  a012 3890 613d 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..8.a=..........
        0x0030:  0011 32c5 0011 5347 0103 0307            ..2...SG....
17:21:45.361789 IP 172.16.99.21.36521 > 172.16.99.15.3128: . ack 1626710396 win 457 <nop,nop,timestamp 1135431 1127109>
        0x0000:  4500 0034 5697 4000 4006 c5e7 ac10 6315  E..4V.@.@.....c.
        0x0010:  ac10 630f 8ea9 0c38 668a 05d2 60f5 a17c  ..c....8f...`..|
        0x0020:  8010 01c9 1e6c 0000 0101 080a 0011 5347  .....l........SG
        0x0030:  0011 32c5                                ..2.
17:21:45.407930 IP 172.16.99.21.36521 > 172.16.99.15.3128: P 1720321490:1720321613(123) ack 1626710396 win 457 <nop,nop,timestamp 1135442 1127109>
        0x0000:  4500 00af 5698 4000 4006 c56b ac10 6315  E...V.@.@..k..c.
        0x0010:  ac10 630f 8ea9 0c38 668a 05d2 60f5 a17c  ..c....8f...`..|
        0x0020:  8018 01c9 1ee7 0000 0101 080a 0011 5352  ..............SR
        0x0030:  0011 32c5 434f 4e4e 4543 5420 6563 686f  ..2.CONNECT.echo
        0x0040:  2e77 6562 736f 636b 6574 2e6f 7267 3a34  .websocket.org:4
        0x0050:  3433 2048 5454 502f 312e 310d 0a48 6f73  43.HTTP/1.1..Hos
        0x0060:  743a 2065 6368 6f2e 7765 6273 6f63 6b65  t:.echo.websocke
        0x0070:  742e 6f72 670d 0a50 726f 7879 2d43 6f6e  t.org..Proxy-Con
        0x0080:  6e65 6374 696f 6e3a 206b 6565 702d 616c  nection:.keep-al
        0x0090:  6976 650d 0a43 6f6e 6e65 6374 696f 6e3a  ive..Connection:
        0x00a0:  206b 6565 702d 616c 6976 650d 0a0d 0a    .keep-alive....
17:21:45.408347 IP 172.16.99.15.3128 > 172.16.99.21.36521: . ack 1720321613 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1127121 1135442>
        0x0000:  4500 0034 93b9 4000 4006 88c5 ac10 630f  E..4..@.@.....c.
        0x0010:  ac10 6315 0c38 8ea9 60f5 a17c 668a 064d  ..c..8..`..|f..M
        0x0020:  8010 0072 c795 0000 0101 080a 0011 32d1  ...r..........2.
        0x0030:  0011 5352                                ..SR
17:21:45.423007 IP 172.16.99.15.3128 > 172.16.99.21.36521: P 1626710396:1626710435(39) ack 1720321613 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1127124 1135442>
        0x0000:  4500 005b 93ba 4000 4006 889d ac10 630f  E..[..@.@.....c.
        0x0010:  ac10 6315 0c38 8ea9 60f5 a17c 668a 064d  ..c..8..`..|f..M
        0x0020:  8018 0072 bdab 0000 0101 080a 0011 32d4  ...r..........2.
        0x0030:  0011 5352 4854 5450 2f31 2e30 2032 3030  ..SRHTTP/1.0.200
        0x0040:  2043 6f6e 6e65 6374 696f 6e20 6573 7461  .Connection.esta
        0x0050:  626c 6973 6865 640d 0a0d 0a              blished....
17:21:45.423041 IP 172.16.99.21.36521 > 172.16.99.15.3128: . ack 1626710435 win 457 <nop,nop,timestamp 1135446 1127124>
        0x0000:  4500 0034 5699 4000 4006 c5e5 ac10 6315  E..4V.@.@.....c.
        0x0010:  ac10 630f 8ea9 0c38 668a 064d 60f5 a1a3  ..c....8f..M`...
        0x0020:  8010 01c9 1e6c 0000 0101 080a 0011 5356  .....l........SV
        0x0030:  0011 32d4                                ..2.
17:22:15.649132 IP 172.16.99.21.36521 > 172.16.99.15.3128: F 1720321613:1720321613(0) ack 1626710435 win 457 <nop,nop,timestamp 1143003 1127124>
        0x0000:  4500 0034 569a 4000 4006 c5e4 ac10 6315  E..4V.@.@.....c.
        0x0010:  ac10 630f 8ea9 0c38 668a 064d 60f5 a1a3  ..c....8f..M`...
        0x0020:  8011 01c9 1e6c 0000 0101 080a 0011 70db  .....l........p.
        0x0030:  0011 32d4                                ..2.
17:22:15.650241 IP 172.16.99.15.3128 > 172.16.99.21.36521: F 1626710435:1626710435(0) ack 1720321614 win 114 <nop,nop,timestamp 1134681 1143003>
        0x0000:  4500 0034 93bb 4000 4006 88c3 ac10 630f  E..4..@.@.....c.
        0x0010:  ac10 6315 0c38 8ea9 60f5 a1a3 668a 064e  ..c..8..`...f..N
        0x0020:  8011 0072 8c5b 0000 0101 080a 0011 5059  ...r.[........PY
        0x0030:  0011 70db                                ..p.
17:22:15.650255 IP 172.16.99.21.36521 > 172.16.99.15.3128: . ack 1626710436 win 457 <nop,nop,timestamp 1143003 1134681>
        0x0000:  4500 0034 569b 4000 4006 c5e3 ac10 6315  E..4V.@.@.....c.
        0x0010:  ac10 630f 8ea9 0c38 668a 064e 60f5 a1a4  ..c....8f..N`...
        0x0020:  8010 01c9 1e6c 0000 0101 080a 0011 70db  .....l........p.
        0x0030:  0011 5059                                ..PY
```

It's not that the proxy is having an issue with Java TLS connections.  If I instead (still using Java 8) make a vanilla HTTPS connection (say to `https://www.google.com`) through the proxy I see the same `CONNECT` being sent by the client and the same `Connection established` being sent back by the proxy, but then the TLS handshake, etc. proceed normally and the request/response finishes normally.

Frankly, I'm stumped as to what is going on (or rather not going on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue 100% as described in the question. I used Squid version 3.5.17 (Windows 10 64bit),
a local Tomcat using a self-signed certificate with an "echo" web-socket and Java 7 (but I don't think Java 8 makes any difference).

Everything worked OK when I used `org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles:tyrus-standalone-client:1.11` instead of `1.12`.

I decided to use the previous version when I found this bugfix:

2015/Nov/13: Grizzly transport was unable to open wss connection via HTTP proxy
([github-commit](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/commit/c2def691f622485a567ea2c08a45a44b7b629542)).

Version 1.11 was released Jun 2015 and version 1.12 Sep 2015, I expect the fix to be in version 1.13
(see also the [pom history](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/commits/master/containers/grizzly-client/pom.xml)).

The solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31757377/3080094) might be related (2015/Aug/21).

For reference, the output from 1.12 (there is a hard-coded timeout of 30 seconds 
in `org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer.CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT` so you have to wait a while before the error appears).

```
05:07:25.514 [Grizzly(1) SelectorRunner] TRACE o.g.t.c.g.c.GrizzlyClientFilter - handleConnect
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
05:07:25.651 [Grizzly(1)] DEBUG o.g.t.c.g.c.GrizzlyClientFilter - handleRead websocket: null content-size=0 headers=
HttpResponsePacket (
  status=200
  reason=Connection established
  protocol=HTTP/1.1
  content-length=-1
  committed=false
  headers=[]
)
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8443/wstest/ws/echoAsyncAnnotation' failed.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket._connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket.access$000(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket$1.call(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket$1.call(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket.connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:249)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer.openClientSocket(GrizzlyClientContainer.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:663)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:712)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:866)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:511)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:355)
    at nl.fw.wsclienttest.WsClient.echoDemo(WsClient.java:69)
    at nl.fw.wsclienttest.WsClient.main(WsClient.java:41)
```

And the code for the totally unsecure test-client I used:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.websocket.*;

import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler;

public class WsClient {

    static {
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
    }

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WsClient.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.getProperties().put("javax.net.debug", "ssl,handshake,data,sslctx");
        try {
            new WsClient().echoDemo();
            log.info("done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // localhost does not work via squid proxy
    String destUri = "wss://127.0.0.1:8443/wstest/ws/echoAsyncAnnotation";
    String proxyUri = "http://localhost:3128";
    volatile Session wsSession = null;

    void echoDemo() throws Exception {

        final ClientEndpointConfig cec = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().build();
        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
        client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, proxyUri);
        client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.SHARED_CONTAINER, false);

        SSLContext sslCtx = createAllTrustingContext();
        SslEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator = new SslEngineConfigurator(sslCtx, true, false, false);
        sslEngineConfigurator.setHostVerificationEnabled(false); //skip host verification
        client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.SSL_ENGINE_CONFIGURATOR, sslEngineConfigurator);
        // time-out is set to 30 seconds for all operations, so handshake timeout does not work ...
        // see org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer.CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
        client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT, 3000);
        final CountDownLatch messageLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        client.connectToServer(new Endpoint() {

            @Override
            public void onOpen(final Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
                try {
                    session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onMessage(String message) {
                            log.info("Received message: {}", message);
                            wsSession = session;
                            messageLatch.countDown();
                        }
                    });
                    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello world");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, cec, new URI(destUri));
        try {
            messageLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (wsSession != null) {
                wsSession.close();
            }
        } finally {
            client.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static SSLContext createAllTrustingContext() throws Exception {

        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init((KeyStore) null, "changeit".toCharArray());
        ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[] { new TrustServerCertAlways() }, null);
        return ctx;
    }

    static class TrustServerCertAlways implements X509TrustManager {

        @Override public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            log.debug("Trusting all client certificates.");
        }

        @Override public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)   throws CertificateException {
            log.debug("Trusting all server certificates.");
        }

        @Override public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            log.debug("No accepted issuers.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

1.11 worked fine.  I'll keep an eye out for 1.13.